# Retrieve MemSiteAccId from Yodlee

Tags: yodlee

The API Call - **getSiteRefreshInfo** in Yodlee API asks for the *memSiteAccId*.
I thought it is the same as **itemAccountId** that we got from Transactions. However, its not the same. Then, how do I retrieve *memSiteAccId* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you add an account using Site Based API(addSiteAccount1) you'll get- siteAccountId in the response. This is same as MemSiteAccountId, and you need to use the same to pass as an input in getSiteRefreshInfo.